# Website returns 500 error when Debug is switched to False in Django Heroku application

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku. Everything works perfectly when the debug is set to true however when I set the debug to false it returns a 500 error. I'm very sure this has something to do with how I'm rendering my static files. My app can't seem to find my static files when in production.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('main.urls')),
path('', include('moderator.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),]
handler404 = main_views.error_404
handler500 = main_views.error_500
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here's everything in my application that regarding static file storeage(I also set up amazon s3 to handle user uploads):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET', '')
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
#static media settings
STATIC_URL = 'https://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + 'media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if your remove "if settings.DEBUG:" in
```
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```
does the problem still show up?

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Trying looking into the reasons you're getting the errors, do that by `manage.py check --deploy`. I'd highly recommend going through the documentation [here].(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your ALLOWED_HOSTS setting or have you added this setting in your setting.py

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '*' ]